Trouble Performing SSH Agent Forwarding with Raspberry PI Using VSCode Remote Development Extension
When I SSH into my Raspberry Pi using VSCode Remote Development, SSH agent forwarding won't work. When I run ssh-add -l on my local Mac machine, I get an identity. When I'm logged into the Raspberry Pi on VSCode and run ssh-add -l, I get "Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory."
However, if I were to SSH into my Raspberry Pi using my Mac terminal, the agent forwarding works. The only way I'm able to get agent forwarding to work using VSCode is uninstalling the VSCode server from the Raspberry Pi server before I open up a connection. I was wondering if anyone else has run into this issue before and how they fixed it.
ssh config file:
  Host PiAware
    HostName 192.168.2.149
    User pi
    ForwardAgent yes


Output to console as VSCode connects to Raspberry Pi using SSH:
18:14:55.529] Log Level: 2
[18:14:55.533] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2250694177617265227d", attempt 1
[18:14:55.533] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[18:14:55.533] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[18:14:55.534] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[18:14:55.537] VS Code version: 1.90.2
[18:14:55.537] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.112.0
[18:14:55.537] darwin arm64
[18:14:55.537] SSH Resolver called for host: PiAware
[18:14:55.537] Setting up SSH remote "PiAware"
[18:14:55.539] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/wl/ypq0_yb91cgf0wgsnqn8r4v00000gp/T/vscode-remote-ssh-b9812f84-install.lock
[18:14:55.539] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/kirthan.reddy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-b9812f84-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb-0.112.0-es/data.json
[18:14:55.540] Using commit id "5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb" and quality "stable" for server
[18:14:55.541] Install and start server if needed
[18:14:55.542] PATH: /usr/local/bin:/Users/kirthan.reddy/.local/bin:/Users/kirthan.reddy/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/usr/local/munki:/usr/local/munkireport
[18:14:55.542] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[18:14:55.548] > OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

[18:14:55.550] askpass server listening on /var/folders/wl/ypq0_yb91cgf0wgsnqn8r4v00000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-416d80e8cb0772185d934dbd8fd80c34925eb9a5.sock
[18:14:55.550] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/wl/ypq0_yb91cgf0wgsnqn8r4v00000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-3afc88df5328ef141de4e0dd78dcc302d14ef820.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","54605","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","PiAware"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/kirthan.reddy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-b9812f84-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb-0.112.0-es/data.json"}
[18:14:55.550] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.NHKpniMm6n/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/kirthan.reddy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/kirthan.reddy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/wl/ypq0_yb91cgf0wgsnqn8r4v00000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-416d80e8cb0772185d934dbd8fd80c34925eb9a5.sock"}
[18:14:55.551] Spawned 3629
[18:14:55.636] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 54605 -o ConnectTimeout=15 PiAware
[18:14:55.638] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=3638
[18:14:55.641] stderr> OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[18:14:55.971] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:tQP+/g0wxrkK5jbYI48WtEPI9ibXWmwfCRCXkUEsEJU
[18:14:56.177] Got askpass request: {"request":" pi@192.168.2.149's password:"}
[18:14:56.177] Showing password prompt
[18:14:56.178] Listening for interwindow password on /var/folders/wl/ypq0_yb91cgf0wgsnqn8r4v00000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-48d1f60059ad6e246c87efa468562be91abaaf7f.sock
[18:14:56.178] Writing password prompt to globalState
[18:14:57.981] Got password response
[18:14:57.981] Interactor gave response: ***********
[18:14:57.981] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[18:14:59.351] stderr> Authenticated to 192.168.2.149 ([192.168.2.149]:22) using "password".
[18:15:00.363] > Linux piaware 5.15.76-v7+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 12:13:17 GMT 2022 armv7l
> 
> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
> the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
> individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
> 
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by applicable law.
[18:15:00.834] > ready: f6aaaebd0c5a
[18:15:00.872] > Linux 5.15.76-v7+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 12:13:17 GMT 2022
[18:15:00.872] Platform: linux
[18:15:00.878] > /bin/bash
[18:15:00.879] Shell: bash
[18:15:00.879] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[18:15:00.902] > bash version:  5.1.4(1)-release
[18:15:01.014] > f6aaaebd0c5a: running
[18:15:01.092] > Found existing installation at /home/pi/.vscode-server...
> Starting VS Code CLI... "/home/pi/.vscode-server/code-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb" command-shell --cli-data-dir "/home/pi/.vscode-server/cli" --on-port --on-host=127.0.0.1 --parent-process-id 11334 &> "/home/pi/.vscode-server/.cli.5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb.log" < /dev/null
[18:15:01.095] > printenv:
[18:15:01.118] >     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-2WxfoST6Pg/agent.11308
>     NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
>     PWD=/home/pi
>     LOGNAME=pi
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     HOME=/home/pi
>     LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/pi/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.2.214 54606 192.168.2.149 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     USER=pi
>     SHLVL=1
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=40
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     SSH_CLIENT=192.168.2.214 54606 22
>     PATH=/home/pi/.cargo/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
>     TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[18:15:01.135] > Removing old logfile at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.cli.5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb.log
[18:15:01.147] > Spawned remote CLI: 11353
[18:15:01.374] > Waiting for server log...
[18:15:01.680] > Waiting for server log...
[18:15:01.810] > Waiting for server log...
[18:15:01.947] > f6aaaebd0c5a: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK==/tmp/ssh-2WxfoST6Pg/agent.11308==
> DISPLAY====
> listeningOn==127.0.0.1:38869==
> osReleaseId==raspbian==
> arch==armv7l==
> vscodeArch==armhf==
> bitness==32==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> serverStartTime==800==
> execServerToken==11a1aa11-11a1-111a-1111-11aa11aa11a1==
[18:15:01.948] > f6aaaebd0c5a: end
[18:15:01.948] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK==/tmp/ssh-2WxfoST6Pg/agent.11308==
DISPLAY====
listeningOn==127.0.0.1:38869==
osReleaseId==raspbian==
arch==armv7l==
vscodeArch==armhf==
bitness==32==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
serverStartTime==800==
execServerToken==11a1aa11-11a1-111a-1111-11aa11aa11a1==
[18:15:01.948] Remote server is listening on port 38869
[18:15:01.948] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":38869},"osReleaseId":"raspbian","arch":"armv7l","sshAuthSock":"/tmp/ssh-2WxfoST6Pg/agent.11308","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/1000","platform":"linux","execServerToken":"11a1aa11-11a1-111a-1111-11aa11aa11a1"},"serverStartTime":800,"installUnpackCode":""}
[18:15:01.949] Persisting server connection details to /Users/kirthan.reddy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-b9812f84-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb-0.112.0-es/data.json
[18:15:01.950] Starting forwarding server. local port 54607 -> socksPort 54605 -> remotePort 38869
[18:15:01.950] Forwarding server listening on port 54607
[18:15:01.950] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[18:15:01.952] Tunneled port 38869 to local port 54607
[18:15:01.952] Resolved "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2250694177617265227d" to "port 54607"
[18:15:01.955] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2250694177617265227d
[18:15:01.955] Resolving exec server at port 54607
[18:15:01.967] [Forwarding server port 54607] Got connection 0
[18:15:01.971] [Forwarding server port 54607] Got connection 1
[18:15:02.712] Exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2250694177617265227d created and cached
[18:15:02.714] ------




[18:15:02.727] [server] Checking /home/pi/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb/log.txt and /home/pi/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb/pid.txt for a running server...
[18:15:02.775] [server] Found running server (pid=10654)


In order for ssh to be able to use keys loaded in ssh-agent, it needs to be able to find it.
This means it needs environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK and it needs to have a permission to access the file/socket it points to.
My guess would be that what's happening here is that when you start ssh from within VS Code, it doesn't have this variable set. This might be due to the launcher using a different set of environment variables for VS Code than your shell. So the first step would be to run something like env from your VS Code and see which variables are set, and in particular check if SSH_AUTH_SOCK is among them and correct.
If this is indeed the case, as one way of working around it you could try to launch VS Code from a terminal where ssh is working (i.e. it can connect to the agent) as this would normally inherit the variables of the shell it is being started from.
Another possible workaround would be to set this variable manually, either in VS Code run profile, or by using a shell script (wrapper around ssh) that does it for you.
Third, you could also add the keys to your ssh config file and avoid using ssh-agent altogether.
